# Mongoose Schema enum and typescript enums

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

We have a Typescript based NodeJs project that makes use of Mongoose. We are trying to find an appropriate way to define an enum field on a Mongoose schema, based on a Typescript enum.
Taking an example enum:

```
enum StatusType {
    Approved = 1,
    Decline = 0,
}
```

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

statusType: {
      type: Number,
      default: StatusType.Approved,
      enum: Object.values(StatusType)
   }
});
```

But we keep getting a validation error but anytime we change the type of the **statusType** to

```
type: String
```

It works but it saves the status as a string like **"0"** instead of **0**

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
statusType: {
  type: Number,
  default: StatusType[StatusType.Approved],
  enum: Object.values(StatusType)
}
```

Comment: i tried this, and still didn't work

Comment: try to do 

enum StatusType {
    Approved,
    Decline
}

statusType: {
  type: String,
  default: StatusType[StatusType.Approved],
  enum: Object.values(StatusType)
} 

If you check the db you'll find statusType as String and this is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript enums are really fuzzy and have a lot of issues, instead try using

```
const StatusType = {
    Decline: 1,
    Approved: 0
} as const;
```